# Protractor + Jasmine + TS. Typings issue: xit return void. How to use xit().pend(reason)

Tags: typescript, protractor

I'm using protractor + jasmine on Typescript for e2e tests.

And I've got an issue while trying to implement some test run by tags

see code below:

```
function testCase(description: string, testSteps: (done?: DoneFn) => 
void, tags?: ReadonlyArray<string>): void {
  const specTagsList: ReadonlyArray<string> = tags || [];
  const tagsToRun: ReadonlyArray<string> = browser.params.tags.split(',');

  if (tagsToRun.length === 0 || specTagsList.some(tag => tagsToRun.indexOf(tag) >= 0)) {
    it(description, testSteps);
  } else {
    xit(description, testSteps)
      .pend(`specTagsList:\t${specTagsList}\ntagsToRun:\t${browser.params.tags}`);
  }
}
```

unfortunately in typings `xit` has declared void return type:

```
declare function xit(expectation: string, assertion?: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout?: number): void;
```

so I cannot use `.pend('reason')` in my code =(

probably someone know solution for such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into this problem, and this is pretty much the same solution, but you could use the suffix `as any` to do the same thing (get around the compiler error) without introducing a new variable:

```
(xit(description, testSteps) as any)
  .pend(`specTagsList:\t${specTagsList}\ntagsToRun:\t${browser.params.tags}`);
```

Or we can globally modify the typing like:

```
declare global {
    function xit(expectation: string, assertion?: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout?: number): any;
}
```

I'm still trying to figure out the proper solution though.

The issue has been posted to the DefinitelyTyped Project:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14000

Answer (score 0):

found solution:

```
export function testCase(description: string, testSteps: (done?: DoneFn) => void, tags?: ReadonlyArray<string>): void {
  const testCaseTagsList: ReadonlyArray<string> = tags || [];
  const tagsToRun: ReadonlyArray<string> = browser.params.tags.split(',');

  if (tagsToRun.length === 0 || testCaseTagsList.some(tag => tagsToRun.indexOf(tag) >= 0)) {
    it(description, testSteps);
  } else {
    // need any due to wrong xit declaration which returns void
    const skippableXit: any = xit(description, testSteps);
    skippableXit.pend(`specTagsList:\t${testCaseTagsList}\ntagsToRun:\t${browser.params.tags}`);
  }
}
```